# How to use multiple IN - Where IN (...) and IN (...)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm tuning performance of my script and I changed the way posts categories are sorted.

I was using successfully the following query.
It selects posts with (130|3|4|5) categories and checks if it also has (73) category init as one post can have multiple categories.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   post 
       LEFT JOIN post_plus 
              ON ( post.id = post_plus.news_id ) 
WHERE  category REGEXP '[[:<:]](130|3|4|5)[[:>:]]' 
       AND category REGEXP '[[:<:]](73)[[:>:]]' 
       AND approve = 1 
ORDER  BY fixed DESC, 
          date DESC 
LIMIT  0, 7
```

Now with a new query I need to perform multiple IN (...) queries instead of `AND category REGEXP '...'`, but for some reason additional `AND categoryid IN` always returns empty result.

```
SELECT *
FROM   post 
       LEFT JOIN post_plus 
              ON ( post.id = post_plus.news_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN post_category 
              ON ( post_category.postid = post.id ) 
WHERE  categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 ) 
AND categoryid IN ( 73 )
       AND approve = 1 
ORDER  BY fixed DESC, 
          date DESC 
LIMIT  0, 7;
```

post_category structure

```
+-----+--------+------------+
| cid | postId | categoryId |
+-----+--------+------------+
| 824 |      7 |         10 |
| 825 |      7 |         13 |
| 826 |      7 |         16 |
| 827 |      7 |         29 |
| 828 |      7 |         71 |
+-----+--------+------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the `postid` for posts that are both in category `73` and in at least one of category id `130, 3, 4, 5` you can use

```
SELECT postid
FROM   post_category
GROUP  BY postid
HAVING MAX(CASE
             WHEN categoryid = 73 THEN 1
           END) = 1
       AND MAX(CASE
                 WHEN categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 ) THEN 1
               END) = 1
```

This can be used in a derived table to join onto your wider query.

Or another possibility is

```
SELECT c1.postid
FROM   post_category c1
       JOIN post_category c2
         ON c1.postid = c2.postid
WHERE  c1.categoryid IN ( 130, 3, 4, 5 )
       AND c2.categoryid = 73
```

Comment: Worked but that was really slow. 7 rows in set (2.45 sec)

Comment: @user2696962 - In that case you could try a self join  instead.

Comment: Can you help me join your second query with the query I posted in my question?

Comment: @user2696962 - Instead of `LEFT JOIN post_category` you can do `LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT c1.postid FROM post_category c1 .... AND c2.categoryid = 73 ) post_category`

Comment: getting `ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: So you've missed out the alias then. That is what the final `post_category` is after the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `INTERSECT`-compound statement:

```
SELECT postid
FROM post_category
WHERE categoryid = 73
INTERSECT
SELECT postid
FROM post_category
WHERE categoryid IN (130, 3, 4, 5)
```

This will select only those `postid`s that have a `categoryid` equal to `73` and at least one of `categoryid` = `130`, `3`, `4`, or `5`.

This query will probably run faster than a aggregate-query (`GROUP BY`), since the sql-server can use the index on `categoryid` (which you hopefully have) to get the relevent `postid`s and then uses a temporary index to compute the intersection (at least thats what sqlite does). If there there are no `postid`s with `categoryid` 73, then the second part of the query is never executed, since the intersection of an empty set with anything else is always just the empty set.

To get your posts, use a subquery:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post
WHERE post.id IN (SELECT postid
                  FROM post_category
                  WHERE categoryid = 73
                  INTERSECT
                  SELECT postid
                  FROM post_category
                  WHERE categoryid IN (130, 3, 4, 5))
```

Also note that you can add more `INTERSECT`-compounds as you like.

Comment: getting `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'intersect  SELECT postid  FROM   dle_post_category  WHERE  categoryid IN (130,3,' at line 1`

Comment: Turns out MySQL does not support intersect.